# TinyMCE - Make a url clickable

Tags: javascript, url, tinymce, clickable

I'm working on a TinyMCE client request. In TinyMCE, a user inputs a url into the editor. (Let's say www.google.com). The user saves the input and "www.google.com" is rendered as plain text inside of a p tag. How can I make this url clickable? Our application is using TinyMCE version 3.5. I would very much appreciate some guidance here as I'm new to the inner workings of TinyMCE. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you've upgraded to TinyMCE 4, add `plugins: "autolink"` to your TinyMCE init function.

If not, [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:autolink](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x%3aautolink)

Comment: Thanks. I had fixed this with 3.5 by adding the "advanced_url" plugin. I will remember your solution when we upgrade to version 4.